# Ios Audio Player in all views

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ios6

I have a project with many views controllers in the storyboard. I would like to have an audio controller (same on all views). How could I do to control it independete screen that was?

The idea is that the audio start playing qaundo the application opens and the other screens I can give stop or play.

Sorry my english is terrible.
Someone could help me please?
Thanks

Comment: if you have any idea about how to use AppDelegate file's shared instance then it's easy to achieve your goal and i can help you in that.

Comment: Hi eptdeveloper thanks for the help, i'm new in ios. Do you have an example of a model? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all in your AppDelegate.h file write this code below #import UIKit/UIKit.h

```
#define APPDELEGATE ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

and now import your AppDelegate.h file to your "projectname-Prefix.pch"

now you'll have access of your AppDelegate class in all the viewControllers in your app.

so now create the player start and stop methods in your AppDelegate.m file and call it on any viewController you want as per your requirement.

Hope it helps you and if you have any confusion you can ask me.

Comment: Hi many thanks for the help, itried used your code but doesn't work.

Comment: i put my simple project here https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lckduuyt9oaaul/test.zip with test your code, could you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: have done some modifications please take a look at here https://www.dropbox.com/s/17exju161ebgdvq/test%202.zip

Comment: This is absolutely hideous. The Appdelegate isn't some kind of convenient dumping ground for storing variables or methods. We have things such as OOP, MVC and, in this case, nil-targetted actions.

Answer (score 1):

A `UIViewController` provides life-cycle and state management of a `UIView`, and can contain child view controllers.   Similarly, the underlying UIView can contain a child UIView.

If your player is implemented in a `UIViewController`,  you can simply instantiate it once and then move it to the currently visible parent `UIViewController` (it can only the the child of a single view controller at any one time) using the

`- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController`

method of `UIViewController`

Container view controllers such as `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` provide delegate interfaces (`UINavigationControllerDelegate` and `UITabBarDelegate` respectively) which allow you to get notifications when the currently visible view is about to change.

For the `UINavigationController` you would implement `- (void) navigationController:willShowViewController:animated` to attach the player's view controller to `willShowViewController`.